# Creating Angular/Typescript Interface for parsing Alpha Vantage API JSON return values

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, angular-services, alpha-vantage

I'm creating a project in Angular that uses the Alpha Vantage API to look up stock prices and display historical stock data in a graph, but I'm having trouble creating an interface to store the JSON string that I get back from the API call. I'm aware that I could just call `JSON.parse()`, but since it's a best practice to cast returns from Angular's `HttpClient` into a template for easy access (instead of manually parsing the object returned from `JSON.parse()`, I'd like to figure this out.

So the issue is that the JSON string that is returned from the API call (any of the TIME_SERIES_X calls, to be specific) has variable property names for basically everything after the MetaData. See sample below:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "AAPL",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-09-27 16:00:00",
        "4. Interval": "5min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "2019-09-27 16:00:00": {
            "1. open": "218.6500",
            "2. high": "218.9300",
            "3. low": "218.3700",
            "4. close": "218.8500",
            "5. volume": "630543"
        },
        "2019-09-27 15:55:00": {
            "1. open": "218.8100",
            "2. high": "218.9200",
            "3. low": "218.6200",
            "4. close": "218.6600",
            "5. volume": "545536"
        },
        "2019-09-27 15:50:00": {
            "1. open": "218.7100",
            "2. high": "218.8400",
            "3. low": "218.5800",
            "4. close": "218.8200",
            "5. volume": "260471"
        }
    }
}
```

Both `"Time Series (5min)"` and all of the timestamps vary depending on the timing of the API call and the parameters you give it (more info on Alpha Vantage API [here](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/)).

So, here's what I have so far. Because the `TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY` function has a different metadata structure than the others, I separated it out and use a union type for the metadata section of the `TimeSeriesResponseFormat` interface.

```
interface SeriesFormat {
    [entryTitle: string]: {
        ["1. open"]: string,
        ["2. high"]: string,
        ["3. low"]: string,
        ["4. close"]: string,
        ["5. volume"]: string
    }[]
}

interface IntradayMetadataFormat {
    ["1. Information"]: string,
    ["2. Symbol"]: string,
    ["3. Last Refreshed"]: string,
    ["4. Interval"]: string,
    ["5. Output Size"]: string,
    ["6. Time Zone"]: string
}

interface MetadataFormat {
    ["1. Information"]: string,
    ["2. Symbol"]: string,
    ["3. Last Refreshed"]: string,
    ["4. Output Size"]: string,
    ["5. Time Zone"]: string
}

export interface TimeSeriesResponseFormat {
    ["Meta Data"]: MetadataFormat | IntradayMetadataFormat,
    [seriesTitle: string]: SeriesFormat
}
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Property '["Meta Data"]' of type 'IntradayMetadataFormat | MetadataFormat' is not assignable to string index type 'SeriesFormat'.
```

Unless I'm mistaken, since ["Meta Data"] is a string being used as an index signature, Angular/Typescript is trying to cast it as a `SeriesFormat` interface, and that's why it's throwing the error. What I'm confused about is how to actually get this to work as intended. I'd appreciate any advice you guys have.

Comment: Since you don't know what are key names so does typescript, the close you can come up with is `interface TimeSeriesResponseFormat { [key: string]: MetadataFormat | IntradayMetadataFormat | SeriesFormat }` and series format doesn't have an array remove []

Comment: This is just an example of why Typescript doesn't always help - all it is doing is creating work for you. It is not adding any value to the exercise :)